# Sending user-mode interrupts on x86

Tags: linux, x86, signals, interrupt

On Linux x86, can I send interrupts (e.g., triggered by a timer, or other other mechanism), which will be handled by code running in user mode?

Assuming the answer is yes (and it is almost certainly yes, see e.g., [timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)), **does delivering this interrupt occur solely in user mode**, or is there some kernel transition involved (e.g., the interrupt is initially handled by the kernel, which then sends the signal to the user process).

Comment: You could always write invalid code that code that attempts to perform invalid operations that would generate some type of exception, which you can then catch in the form of a Linux signal in user mode. I'm not sure whether this is what you meant by "send interrupts." A lot of code will get executed until you signal handler gets invoked. AFAIK, there is no built-in mechanism in Linux that allows to directly hook up your own (user-mode) interrupt handler or defined your own entry in the IDT, but I think it can be done with some manual effort.

Comment: In Linux the interrupt handlers all run in ring 0. The kernel would raise a signal within usermode so the appropriate user mode handler can be called.

Answer (score 4):

All kernel timer interfaces work by delivering *signals* to user-space processes, after handling the timer interrupt inside the kernel (or otherwise noticing that or waiting until the deadline has been reached).

There are many *big* obstacles to having an interrupt handler run in ring 3, or from a user-space virtual address that's only mapped by one specific process.  (Even if you pin that memory so it can't be paged, it is still only mapped at all when CR3 is set to that process's page tables.  x86 uses virtual addresses in the IDT (interrupt descriptor table) and the page must be mapped when the interrupt fires (or else you get a page fault, I guess, which you really don't want to happen totally asynchronously).  This is not a problem for normal kernel interrupt handlers; it always keeps kernel code mapped to the same virtual address across all user-space page tables. )

A kernel API that allowed registering a user-space function pointer as a ring 0 interrupt handler would be handing the keys to the kingdom to that userspace process, literally running with kernel privileges, so that's pretty much unreasonable.

---

It is technically possible for x86 to have an interrupt handler that runs in ring 3, but if the interrupt fired while in ring 0, `iret` would fault instead of returning back to the kernel code that got interrupted.

An interrupt handler would have to be written specially to return with `iret`, and to preserve all registers.  e.g. `__attribute__((interrupt_handler))`  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html.  And any other process on the same core would be at the mercy of this process; **any bugs in this (like destroying some architectural state, or dirtying SSE/AVX regs) could affect *other* processes.**  (If you can figure out how to get code in one process to run while CR3 might be set for another process...)

Avoiding deadlocks would also be a big issue; in the kernel there are a lot of limits on what you can do in an interrupt handler proper (the "top half") because it can run asynchronously in between any other instruction (unless you disable interrupts on that core).

---

I don't think it's really plausible for Linux to let you do this; even if you somehow solve all the (very hard) problems and even get the handler to run in ring 3, the kernel still has to trust it not to step on the architectural state of any other process.

There is precedent for things like X servers getting privileges to run `in`/`out` instructions (via `iopl`) and/or access `/dev/mem` (which would in theory let it steal info from other processes).  But this would be even worse, and give you easy access to snapshots of register state from other processes.

Comment: Oh you can have an interrupt handler running at a privilege level other than 0 but you'd only ever be able to IRET back out of that handler to the same or less privileged ring without faulting. So if you had an interrupt handler in the IDT with a CS that was ring 3 you'd never be able to IRET to Interrupt 0,1,2 which means you'd be limited to running ring 3 code only since you'd never be able to return to any other privilege level from the interrupt handler. Of course if your interrupt handler is running in 3 it would be limited in what it could do without using some kind of call gate.

Comment: Call gates can allow a less privileged ring access to code running at more privileged levels.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks, fixed.  There were some other showstopper bugs (like virtual memory) that I didn't think of the first time; added those.